# Backup app to use with Amazon Cloud Drive?

Tags: backup, aws

I am backing up my iMac locally using Time Machine, and now I am looking for a cloud backup to provide offsite redundancy. I have signed up for Amazon's unlimited storage option for their Cloud Drive, and I have been testing Arq as a local backup app. Arq works okay, but it's lacking some features, such as the ability to restrict uploads to certain hours, such as 10:00 PM to 6:00 AM.

Can you recommend a backup app that works with Amazon Cloud Drive, and provides good configuration options? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I use Syncovery at work on some windows server to back up to our Amazon S3 account. It works well and reliably and has a number of scheduling features. Unfortunately I have not had the opportunity to use it on the Mac, but you might want to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know whether this is a new option, but Arq actually allows you to restrict operations to a specific time window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The application [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/apps/expandrive/) allows you to mount your Amazon Cloud Drive as a network drive -- this could be useful for you.  ExpanDrive works with many other cloud services as well, including Amazon S3, Google Drive, Dropbox (for use with selective syncing), OneDrive, Box, any WebDAV or SFTP account, etc.  It doesn't do scheduling or automations, however; it just gives you access to your cloud storage account as a network drive -- one would have to write one's own scripts to automate tasks.